# Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_get_parent: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk

I am trying to access a `GTK Widget`, right now any property of the widget will do but I keep on getting the error:

```
Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__FUNCTIONAME: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
```

This is my code so far, well the relevant bits:

```
///////// FILE 1 /////////////////

GtkWidget *textbox1;                        //declared at the top of the file 
GtkTextBuffer *text;

void onscreen (int type, char* key)
{
    if (type == -1) {
        //remove widget
    } 
    else if (type == 1) {
        gtk_widget_destroy(GTK_WIDGET(textbox1));     
        //THE OFFENDING LINE  ^^^
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    /*more code*/

    textbox1 = gtk_text_view_new();
    text = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(textbox1));
    GtkTextIter iter;
    gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_offset(text, &iter, 0);
    gtk_text_buffer_insert(text, &iter, "plain text\n", -1); 

    vbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 8);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);

    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), hbox, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), zbarwidgets, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), GTK_WIDGET(results), FALSE, FALSE, 0);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();
    return(0);
}

///////// FILE 1 /////////////////
```

I then have more code in another file (headers etc... are included fine) which calls the first function in file 2, like so:

```
///////// FILE 2 /////////////////

static inline int window_draw (window_t *w) {
    /* do some stuff */
    onscreen(1, sym->data);
    /* do some stuff */
}

///////// FILE 2 /////////////////
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you use `gdk_threads_`

Comment: @drahnr i was using it as before the program was using threads, made a few changes but forgot to remove those, have done so now

Comment: What does the stack trace look like when you're ending up in `onscreen`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson sorry give me a minute, I have to set some flags before going into GDB  so I'm having a bit of trouble getting the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Your error is not in the code shown above, some other function does modify `textbox1`

Also note that `gtk_widget_get_parent` will always return `NULL` according to the code shown.

Why do you use `gdk_threads_*` don't do that unless you *really* run into threading issues - also not it being deprecated (afaik).

Comment: What do you mean some "other function" modifys textbox1 and I'm not interested in `gtk_widget_get_parent` at this point in the code I am actually trying to `destroy` the widget but because of the error coming up I tried it with different functions but still got the same thing, I have changed the code to give it more context from `gtk_widget_get_parent` to `gtk_widget_destroy` but I still get the same error

Comment: I bet `/*more code*/` contains a call to `onscreen(...)` which is the rootcause of your troubles. Post your complete code, this is pointless.

Comment: note i have added back the threads as without it there the program crashes anytime any drawing gets done

Comment: Try to do `textbox1 = gtk_text_view_new();` after `gtk_init()` - if that does not work, try removing code until the problem vanishes. Also - again - you did not post the complete code but another chunk. From the code postet it is not clear why you would need `gdk_threads_*`-calls at all.